# Счетчик выбранных элементов (checkbox) без JS, скрывать блок счетчика если элементы не выбраны

Tags: css

Как сделать счетчика выбранных элементов (checkbox) стандартными средствами без использования JS?
Если выбранные элементы отсутствуют, блок со счетчиком должен скрываться.

Answer (score 4):

Написал небольшой пример счетчика выбранных элементов (checkbox).
Пригодится в качестве ознакомления возможностей CSS.

```
input:checked {
  counter-increment: list;
}
.result {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .result {
  display: block;
}
.result::after {
  content: "Selected: "counter(list);
}
```

P.S Ждем [переменные в CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

**Демо:**

```css
input:checked {
  counter-increment: list;
}
.result {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .result {
  display: block;
}
.result::after {
  content: "Selected: "counter(list);
}
```

```html
<h3>Select any checkbox</h3>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="result"></div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZWXOZ)